# Delayed Exchange not directly publish message

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I have tried to create a queue and I want to create delayed exchange and send message to a corresponding queue. But I find that just after creating the exchange, the message is not sent to the queue (it will not also be consumed as well).

But this strange thing happens, after a while, lets say 30 minutes, I tried again with the same code, the message is sent to the queue and consumed.

Here is my application.properties look like:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=output
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.routing-key-expression=output.webhook.delay
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.required-groups=webhook.delay
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=output
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=webhook.delay
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.dead-letter-routing-key=output.webhook.delay.dlq
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.exchange-type=direct
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.lazy=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.delayed-exchange=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.dead-letter-routing-key=output.webhook.delay.dlq
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.exchange-type=direct
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.lazy=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.delayed-exchange=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.delay-expression=3000
```

In the Admin Page of RabbitMQ it shows that it create exchange with exchange type: x-delayed-message and I have installed delayed exchange plugin.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.